# React Generic Props gets an error whilst using function in props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a basic snippet code where the props is generic, and I try to provide a function which is already dependent on the generic type. For non-function all goes good, but when I try to provide a function in the props I have an error.

```
import React from 'react';

import { concatClasses } from '@/utils/component';

import type { IOption } from '../interfaces/option';

import classes from './Filter.module.scss';

interface IProps<T> {
    readonly title: string;
    readonly options: IOption<T>[];
    readonly selectedOption: T;
    readonly onSelectOption: (value: T) => void;
}

const FilterView = <T,>(props: React.PropsWithChildren<IProps<T>>) => {
    return (
        <div className={classes['container']}>
            <h5 className={classes['container__title']}>{props.title}</h5>

            {props.options.map((option, index) => (
                <button
                    key={index}
                    className={concatClasses(
                        classes,
                        'container__option',
                        props.selectedOption === option.value ? 'container__option--selected' : null,
                    )}
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() => props.onSelectOption(option.value)}
                >
                    {option.label}
                </button>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

FilterView.displayName = 'FilterView';
FilterView.defaultProps = {};

export default React.memo(FilterView);
```

All good by here, but then I try to use this component and get an error:

```
import React from 'react';

import type { IOption } from '../interfaces/option';

import FilterView from './Filter.view';

interface IProps<T> {
    readonly title: string;
    readonly options: IOption<T>[];
    readonly selectedOption: T;
    readonly onSelectOption: (value: T) => void;
}

const Filter = <T,>(props: React.PropsWithChildren<IProps<T>>) => (
    <FilterView
        title={props.title}
        options={props.options}
        selectedOption={props.selectedOption}
        onSelectOption={props.onSelectOption}
    />
);

Filter.displayName = 'Filter';
Filter.defaultProps = {};

export default React.memo(Filter);
```

The error I get is marked in this line `onSelectOption={props.onSelectOption}`:

```
(property) onSelectOption: (value: unknown) => void
Type '(value: T) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: unknown) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'T'.
      'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'unknown'.ts(2322)
```

Could anyone tell why?

The `IOption` interface:

```
export interface IOption<T> {
    readonly value: T;
    readonly label: string;
}
```

Comment: Could you share your `IOptions` interface?

Comment: @MichaelBrenndoerfer
What do you mean? You have the interface included in the code.

Comment: My bad, missed it. Why are you using PropsWithChildren if you don't use `children` ?

Comment: @MichaelBrenndoerfer convention considerations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known limitation of [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) type unfortunately: it does not handle the generics of Components.

See https://newdevzone.com/posts/how-to-use-props-with-generics-with-reactmemo

A simple solution consists in augmenting that type with an overload:

```
declare module "react" { // augment React types
  function memo<A, B>(Component: (props: A) => B): (props: A) => React.ReactElement | null
  // return type is same as ReturnType<ExoticComponent<any>>
}

const Filter = <T,>(props: React.PropsWithChildren<IProps<T>>) => (
    <FilterView
        title={props.title}
        options={props.options}
        selectedOption={props.selectedOption}
        onSelectOption={props.onSelectOption} // Okay
    />
);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgEkB5MGYCagHgBUAfHADe5OBLhEUAEx4AbAJ5wAbinkBXJAC44-CpKmo51JXHkoARknm6AzjCg0A5hQC+lGnQZNWABRwwOwFhMUNpEzMuGHkdOAcnaldxSQiFZQhObmo7XXYsnhCAbQBdA1TjdPibJAwkGQ4uHl19FIk00wzqAGUajEbs3QAKNU04-gBKOABeYRUIYBl3SjQeBzgAMWB5bwA1YCQAdxm4AQAaQSGwQNzEYhgAOgDMuwB1YBgACwBhT+2ZIh8FjPIIhQRTWaiNpGGAaKDUOBDaGGXgyYAqQTIwySXifACsghE1xeD2isTcvAA9PjMVjsaJiUEHpkmjkHiAUGAhkMWdkznAaDIkAAPCHCJH0yU4ywaGAwHh0qXYgDWSEU0xEgpFHiVurgMEUYCQ0wARDK5TwTYq9XAeN95MA0MqNUMxXBGXZmT0+jABjweQVqA9RloJjqbZJMRHJSJeTwHhZrPJw9Gqeb5dQo3qJmHFVS0RjoRN3BRyEK0BYiHAQBAZBpYnATdIMCbRHBKZS4CgNM4QEhaHd0PADUa7NDMBpqBhstWkDXeABBfkAIUu31wkGo-Zgww9ugXbuXE13N33buQQ4eF4wAFFYn2BwAfODUevyaEdmFwhEj5jAOzxCgfZdgByCwvC-CGkgvA3sKEBcGg67gDw268Cg1CKIImIeOQqw5PAWw7PQ+xHLBkCwPUJzXo8fY1kMhF7AchzFp4tD0IwaDMMCNwAEwhFC4SVJ0+ofLE9iOC45TtEJZhxjkeR+nwQilFJRiyFUdg+vUiktKpHSyd6sT9IGwwhuMbrzIsyy4WsBHbN4JznJce6DhgTw3O8Xy-P8gK8NxLx8UI4IzOK0K8AxxFMWR0B0DIipksaRI3KSolICm2JyXYGoesygZ2OlhiaUZsWKdlyVFbUJWBgVkg8L0xWlUlJJ1T6iluO2nZsMqKCKB+mIsUAA)

Comment: It does work, but do you know why I have to declare it using the "inline" method?
I tried to put this `declare` statement in `@types/react/index.d.ts` (and I've included `@types` directory in `tsconfig.json` file, but it didn't work.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your feedback! Please what do you mean by "inline method"? We should not have to modify files in `node_modules` (or just for a quick test).

Comment: I mean creating a new `@types` folder, outside `node_modules`

Comment: Difficult to say without further details on your attempt. If I can make a wild guess: in case there is an `import` in the file, then it must be explicitly imported (at least once, anywhere in your project) for it to take effect. You can try avoiding the `import` by replacing it by a `/// <reference types="react" />` directive instead.

Comment: Probably gonna create another Question regarding this issue.
Not related directly with your solution.

Comment: This is the Q if you might know the answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73971947/react-cannot-override-react-types-configuration-outside-a-file

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to augment the type, you can simply tell TS that the exported component is the type you want it to be.

```
export default React.memo(FilterView) as typeof FilterView;
```