# React cannot augment React types configuration with separate file

Tags: reactjs, typescript

There is some type in `react` library I try to overload with an augmentation:

In my project, I created a file: `./@types/react/index.d.ts`, with content:

```
import type React from 'react';

declare module 'react' {
    function memo<A, B>(Component: (props: A) => B): (props: A) => React.ReactElement | null;
}
```

I did to solve some issue I had with TypeScript, which is irrelevant for this question.

I have also provided this `@types` folder in my `./tsconfig.json` file:

```json
"typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./@types"],
```

But issue still shows (i.e. my overload does not affect the initial issue).

If instead, in the file I had the issue, I just paste the code block:

```
declare module 'react' {
    function memo<A, B>(Component: (props: A) => B): (props: A) => React.ReactElement | null;
}
```

...then issue is resolved.

But I rather not use this way, inline-like.
I don't want this declaration to show in the file.

Could anyone tell why the `@types` folder solution does not work?

---

**Reproduce:**
Create a dummy project with boilerplate of CRA:

```
npx create-react-app whatever --template typescript
```

Modify `./tsconfig.json` file with content:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./@types"
    ]  
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Create `./@types/react/index.d.ts` file with content:

```
declare module "react" { // augment React types
    function memo<A, B>(Component: (props: A) => B): (props: A) => React.ReactElement | null
    // return type is same as ReturnType<ExoticComponent<any>>
  }
```

Create `./src/Filter.tsx` file:

```
import React from 'react';

import type { IOption } from './option';

import FilterView from './Filter.view';

interface IProps<T> {
    readonly title: string;
    readonly options: IOption<T>[];
    readonly selectedOption: T;
    readonly onSelectOption: (value: T) => void;
}

const Filter = <T,>(props: React.PropsWithChildren<IProps<T>>) => (
    <FilterView
        title={props.title}
        options={props.options}
        selectedOption={props.selectedOption}
        onSelectOption={props.onSelectOption}
    />
);

Filter.displayName = 'Filter';
Filter.defaultProps = {};

export default React.memo(Filter);
```

Create `Filter.view.tsx` file:

```
import React from 'react';

import type { IOption } from './option';

import classes from './Filter.module.scss';

interface IProps<T> {
    readonly title: string;
    readonly options: IOption<T>[];
    readonly selectedOption: T;
    readonly onSelectOption: (value: T) => void;
}

const FilterView = <T,>(props: React.PropsWithChildren<IProps<T>>) => {
    return (
        <div className={classes['container']}>
            <h5 className={classes['container__title']}>{props.title}</h5>

            {props.options.map((option, index) => (
                <button
                    key={index}
                    className={classes['blabla']}
                    type="button"
                    onClick={() => props.onSelectOption(option.value)}
                >
                    {option.label}
                </button>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

FilterView.displayName = 'FilterView';
FilterView.defaultProps = {};

export default React.memo(FilterView);
```

Create `./option.ts` file:

```
export interface IOption<T> {
    readonly value: T;
    readonly label: string;
}
```

Then you'll see an error in `Filter.tsx` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your module augmentation is in `src/@types/react/index.d.ts`, you should fill your [`typeRoots`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots) tsconfig option with `"./src/@types"` (instead of `"./@types"`):

```json
"typeRoots": [
    "./node_modules/@types",
    "./src/@types"
]
```

> All paths are relative to the `tsconfig.json`.

Note: there is a typo in the import:

```
import React from 'react'; // React first letter uppercase to match how it is used in the file: React.ReactElement
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-silence-qzu12v?file=/tsconfig.json

---

Once you move your global type files *outside* your `./src` directory, they are no longer automatically included in your TS compilation, since the tsconfig mentions only that folder:

```json
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
```

That is why you then have to include the new folder in `typeRoots` option list.

However, TS finds the normal `react` types in `"./node_modules/@types/react"` first, and stops there. Our augmentation file is left behind...

So just make sure to specify your own type root first:

```json
"typeRoots": [
    "./@types", // Own root with augmentations first
    "./node_modules/@types" // base root last
]
```

That way, TS picks up our augmentation file first in `"./@types/react"`. Within that file, it finds the `import "react"` again, and looks for the corresponding "base" `react` type definition file.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-shaw-dw84bj?file=/tsconfig.json:519-566

Comment: I edited the question please read again

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] otherwise we will never see the end

Comment: Done. Please check it now