# React memo function changes the props type of the component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, intellij-idea, next.js, typescript-generics

I have encountered a very weird problem. I have defined two components. If these two components are written in one file, there will be no compilation errors. However, if the two components are written separately, compilation errors will occur.

`test3.tsx`

```js
import React from "react";

type ValueType = number[] | string[] | number | string

interface ISelectChipProps<X extends ValueType> {
  value: X
  setValue: (value: X) => void
}

const SelectChip = <X extends ValueType>({
  value,
  setValue,
}: ISelectChipProps<X>) => {

  return (
    <></>
  )
}

interface IFilterProps {
  value: number[],
  setValue: (value: number[]) => void
}

const Filter = ({setValue, value}: IFilterProps) => {
  return (<SelectChip value={value} setValue={setValue}/>)
}
```

No compile errors in the same file.

`SelectChip`

```js
import React, {memo} from "react";

type ValueType = number[] | string[] | number | string

interface ISelectChipProps<X extends ValueType> {
  value: X
  setValue: (value: X) => void
}

const SelectChip = <X extends ValueType>({
  value,
  setValue,
}: ISelectChipProps<X>) => {

  return (
    <></>
  )
}

export default memo(SelectChip)
```

`Filter.tsx`

```js
import SelectChip from "@/test/SelectChip";

interface IFilterProps {
  value: number[],
  setValue: (value: number[]) => void
}

const Filter = ({setValue, value}: IFilterProps) => {
  return (<SelectChip value={value} setValue={setValue}/>)
}
```

An error was reported in the line of code `<SelectChip value={value} setValue={setValue}/>`:

```
TS2322: Type '(value: number[]) => void' is not assignable to type '(value: ValueType) => void'. Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.     
Type 'ValueType' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.       
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.  
SelectChip.tsx(7, 3): The expected type comes from property 'setValue' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ISelectChipProps<ValueType>'
```

I noticed that IDEA's prompts for these two `setValue` are different:

```
// work fine
ISelectChipProps<X>.setValue: (value: number[]) => void
// error
ISelectChipProps<X>.setValue: (value: ValueType) => void
```

To make sure nothing was missed, I copied the code completely.
The environment I'm using is:

```
"react": "18.2.0"
"typescript": "5.0.4"
"next": "13.3.0"
```

Can you tell me if my usage is wrong, or is there something wrong with the compiler?
If there is a problem with the compiler, how can I locate the problem in one of `IDE`, `TypeScript`, `React`, `Next.js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not same. When you use them in same file, you just use the `SelectChip`. But when you use them in saparated files, you use memoized version of `SelectChip`.

You have:

```
export default memo(SelectChip)
```

Sadly, but it removes the generic prop in SelectChip

What you can do is:

```
export default memo(SelectChip) as typeof SelectChip
```

Comment: You mean the memo function erases the type of Props?

Comment: It changes the type of the component, generic props no longer exist. You can use your component like this: <SelectChip<number> .../>, but you can not put that generic type in the memoized version.

Comment: "_it removes the generic prop_": indeed, this is a known limitation of `memo`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73868787/react-generic-props-gets-an-error-whilst-using-function-in-props/73899911#73899911

Comment: Perfect, a life saver answer I could say, thanks.