# Different props based on a "type" prop, extending types according to a value from interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm attempting to extend a type according to a value from the main `interface`, if the `type == multiline` it will have a `inferface`, if it is `type == icon` it will have another type.

```
import React, { memo, useCallback, ReactNode } from 'react'
import Multiline from 'src/components/Input/variaties/Multiline'
import Icon from './variaties/Icon'
import Default from './variaties/Default'
import Select from './variaties/Select'

interface InputProps {
  type?: 'multiline' | 'icon'
  className?: string
}

interface MultilineInputProps {
  // placeholder: string // Omitting in this example for simplification
  className?: string
  height?: string
}

export interface IconInputProps {
  // placeholder: string
  className?: string
  iconRight?: ReactNode
  iconLeft?: ReactNode
}

type InputComponentProps<T extends 'multiline' | 'icon'> = T extends 'multiline'
  ? MultilineInputProps
  : T extends 'icon'
    ? IconInputProps
    : never

const Input = ({
  type,
  className,
}: InputProps) => {
  const inputComponent = useCallback(() => {
    switch (type) {
      case 'select':
        return (
          <Select options={[]} placeholder={'Icon'} className={className} />
        )
      case 'icon':
        return <Icon placeholder={'Icon'} className={className} />
      case 'multiline':
        return <Multiline placeholder={'Multiline'} className={className} />
      default:
        return <Default placeholder={'Default'} className={className} />
    }
  }, [])

  return inputComponent()
}

export default memo(Input)
```

My tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "strict": true,
    "declaration": true,    
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

The issue is, this does not work: when the `<Input>` is used with a given `type`, it does not accept the corresponding props.

---

In response to the answer:

```
const Input = <T extends 'multiline' | 'icon'>({
  type,
  className,
}: InputProps & {
  type: T
} & InputComponentProps<T>) => {
  // etc.
}
```

[image]

It does not reject the incorrect prop for the type.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that this doesn't work

Comment: Do not _replace_ your original code: this makes answers no longer relevant. You can _add_ further attempts, including based on initial answers attempts, as long as it is clearly stated, so that future readers have a chance to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you would like your `<Input>` Component to accept different props (from `Multiline` or `Icon`) based on the value of the `type` prop?

In that case, you can use your `InputComponentProps` type by inferring the generic type parameter on the `<Input>` Component:

```
// Add a generic type parameter on the Component
const Input = <T extends 'multiline' | 'icon'>({
    type,
    className,
}: InputProps & {
    type: T // Bind the generic type to a prop, so that TS can infer the actual type based on usage (could have directly modified InputProps instead)
} & InputComponentProps<T> // Add (intersect) the extra props based on "type"
) => {
    return null;
}

<>
    <Input type="multiline" height="10" />
    <Input type="multiline" iconLeft="left" />
    {/*                     ~~~~~~~~ Error: Property 'iconLeft' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InputProps & { type: "multiline"; } & MultilineInputProps'. */}
    <Input type="icon" iconLeft="left" />
    <Input type="icon" height="10" />
    {/*                ~~~~~~ Error: Property 'height' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & InputProps & { type: "icon"; } & IconInputProps'. */}
</>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-MnwAIgHbjFCYvVdT7Ww5BgWgoCfVQvFYABuTlFHFbVHnFB1vz1bjzTtJBuKeF43hgDSAEYAAZdOaZTolU-l4AHDStLbXTaQZJkNNYRkYHMyzbBwZoACpokCoKgoAPzC8KwrgABRKAJAGOAxU0BxO3pDzAhICAkEsVQIHgdYVngAsBxkAx7lUegwmjWZMg4YwsqIzDYVnPAFzgTTW38bjZJEIiyhVNtGvoaQADo4D85o8istS7O42knPBFzDO49ymS8lTpozDS5r0kkltMtbol8gLgpOiLIpiuL3ES2AkOkZ5dvSzLstyhsCq478SvUYYKrQKr7lqjRLFnQaiJajN3Fm8Eup64GAxsoMRrGibFIsxQgA)

Note: beware that `React.memo()` loses the generic type parameter inference as is. But you can patch it, see [React Generic Props gets an error whilst using function in props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73868787/react-generic-props-gets-an-error-whilst-using-function-in-props/73899911#73899911)

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDejUYByEAJktiEiBNgK4DOSAwigDasBG6A1nY8gDM4AXzgCoEEHADkUAjGkAoRcAB2MJFAHokcAJKqwtGAAUJYerkVwbcGAE8wSAPwAuGSFqsYwVmqTScAA+MsBoEKpKtnBorCj09IQolG5w9DBQagDmisLKahpaOnAAsl4+fqpIBkam5pY41rYA9M1gcWhIABYQrGRQ7umZqllwrXAA8iDAMD4jcGp2XcCWSAAeye26AtBpoO3AAmEoPhFNNrHxickugxnZ53BdSMBZXTCpQw95iuuQsAt1JptJ19OFVDVjGYIBYrNFWu0dD0+po7sMctFLgkkik0Q9omEIghXu9Ush0DBiGRHoTVAAZJACD7uclEUhIXLKRQOJz6QzGJiSSBVdTQiwAHgAKnB1hpVCRLNJPN5fP5AiFpLTpAA+OAAXke0tlSHliuVFTVj2cpXKqqqkLqMPoj3cRrWcoVoXBUVs1r04IdYud0XcVQAbpplOMAIIkEhwFBwLImzRhOyOXRgFBQG6FOARJa6QXgCImmCKcHpPm1fVwKUy90mz1K22VALBL0RHUACka0R55EeWOulEwuXcgfqcAAZHDbAPXWNmnAAEJqeMwZ5JlOZNDp3kwCAJuBgczYehHzcnOCSgDKMRQqkBAk0hYTGFobH3ui4jHjBYYFBkzgbtwi8eMuhQCM4BIYA5AwVh7DgahYKOJB40nJ1AXSVASAASlyGdqwFIVS1FeopV1GM4xAgpNEYDA8LfWUcxPKdf3Q-MnwAIgHbjFCYvVdT7Ww5BgWgoCfVQvFYABuTkKwiKsHQAJlrVkYAAOkoahuwdPD5MUcZ3hgCxXFadIeAgCMtFYCAAHdNPCEBmgAR1oJB0mAJTmgAdgAZgADgANkC3ywuaOQKQAWmTKpd2i08nVipAYHoaLH2izQJCgaL7OWVh0mihhsmigRaFUDBvNUaK1ES+o-KCgBOFqAEZWoAYgCwKWqa9rFDIS45GQ0gvF0bioowbjcCXBNaCySh1HwClv2DWxysq04nx0iBxWjbAV21bti2FMt3G7JKzLgaNBN1Fc8POy76HcG79V1DTNI0gBRVgqDLDtpPYR5xjEiSnwHBZLHoG4E0sZBxMkyUM3FL61ggHw0BOsiYHFR97G1bUFPFQnonFVTvz1bjzTtJBpueEkYEp1qAAZpuaEnbDJ-kYDUgdKepttptpBkmUp36mTZjmbBwZoACpogVxWlYAP1VtXVbgL6oBy9wxU0BxO3pRkFBgiBPLgVR0YbFZ4ALCHpAMe5VHoMJo1mTIOGMc3Z0w2FZzwBc4Cp1t-G42SRCIsoVTbX36GkTS4Fl5o8lJ8m+e42khfBEXGe48WYElx4udqXmM0pzOnheN5c5Zwvohl+WlabuB1Y1rWdbgPXYCQ6R6erwISDNyxLfgdYba478ZEd4YXbQN37k9jRLB97mgyIgOM3cDPwTDiOfYDVf6njxPk8UcV2cUIA)

---

You could have also simply used a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions):

```
const Input = (props:
  | { type: 'multiline' } & MultilineInputProps
  | { type: 'icon' } & IconInputProps
) {}
```

Since there is no more generic type, `React.memo` does not affect it (even without above patching).

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-nkce1+b98dL+XNMIk-CxFAASnAt0XWHWw5BgWgoFUIUvFYABuTkuwiHtwwAJn7VkYAAOkoagB3DMD0MUbkIF5flKyQEU7Bo1sYDQLp8ApYiqAgKiS3eGALFcVp0h4CB8y0PkAHdCPCEBmgAR1oJB0gvVR6GaAB2ABmAAOAA2HSNMM5o5ApABaetNDCMywHqCykBgegzJQVQzM0CQoDMyTllYdIzIYbIzIEWhVAwVSzLUGz6k03SAE54oARgSgBibSdPi2KkqopUyEuOQ4GoEgvF0AAiUyMBK3AxhLFBaCySh1A4jBmyzWxgtCqUCu4vUAEFsAAISdAcNXACJvRgdwB1syN3B6sCoLgfqwMm6bBLgOaFoIwiCIAUVYKhxuCZD2FXEs4IQpDbwWSx6BuLdLGQeDEINOU9R2tYIB8NARq1ca9Rc+wnSdXJC2UPVgeiPVcObV0Sr9UMkEq54SRgWGEoABkq5oIdsKG1RgPDb1h+Gn0q2kGSZWH9qZLGcZsHBFWiJnmZZgA-dmOfZuAdqgDz3F1TQHETCIKYUOASAgZShU+401hWeAImbGQDHuNSwh62ZMg4YwpcA-HM1fG85XcOHH38ErUIAt9-TDfX6mkQi4ELPJIehomStpMnwVFqnGRgWnHjx2pCblWHPaeF43lRkqMYD6IGaVFmk7gTmuZ5vm4AF2B7BkZGo8CCWpdUGX1nluBFau6QVeGeh1c14BtY0Sw9dqA3lyNpwTc9y3REA9M7cjB2neaPI9WxxQgA)

Comment: Hey, I have made the changes but did not get the expected result, maybe something with the `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: `React.memo` interferes. See updated answer.

Comment: it worked with that new update! Thanks!